# Call stack is show as hex when using WinDbg to analyze a crash dump

Tags: windbg

When I use below command to show the stack, I just get the hex address, even through the module is loaded (checked with command `lm m xx`):

```
0:014> k
Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00000000`88f9b0e0 00000000`305e8a60 0x36f038d
00000000`88f9b0e8 00000000`305e8a60 0x305e8a60
```

Can anybody tell me why?

Answer (score 1):

This is e.g. normal for .NET applications. The intermediate code is part of the assembly / DLL which you can see by `lm`.

However, the intermediate code never gets executed itself. It is processed by the JIT compiler at runtime. The JIT compiler allocates some memory (outside of the DLL) and emits assembler code there.

Since that part of memory is not related to the DLL immediately, WinDbg shows it as hex addresses only.

To work with .NET, load the SOS extension and use commands like

```
.loadby sos clr
!dumpstack
!clrstack
```

or SOSEX with commands like

```
.load <full path to>\sosex.dll
!mk
```